# Derivatives from the value to the power of $1/\rho$

Tags: derivatives, vectors, vector-analysis

I know from check information in the task that $$\frac 1 \rho\cdot  {\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}}(\cos^2\phi\cdot  \tanh z) - \frac \partial {\partial z} \left( \sin2\phi \cdot \ln \sqrt[{\Large\,\rho\,}] \frac{\cosh\rho}{\cosh z} \right)=0$$

After calculation
$$\frac{1}{\rho} \cdot \frac\partial {\partial \phi}(\cos^2\phi\cdot \tanh z)= \frac{1}{\rho} \cdot 2 \cos\phi \sin\phi \cdot \tanh z= \frac{1}{\rho} \cdot \sin2\phi \cdot \tanh z $$

I have problem with the second derivative

\begin{align}
& \frac \partial {\partial z} \left( \sin2\phi \cdot \ln \sqrt[{\Large\,\rho\,}]{\frac{\cosh\rho}{\cosh z}} \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \sin2\phi \cdot \frac 1 {\sqrt[{\Large\,\rho\,}]{\frac{\cosh\rho}{\cosh z}}} \cdot \frac 1 \rho \cdot \left(\frac{\cosh\rho}{\cosh z} \right)^{(1/\rho)-1} \cdot \sinh z \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac 1 \rho \cdot \sin2\phi\cdot
\frac{ \left(\frac{\cosh\rho}{\cosh z} \right)^{(1/\rho)-1}} {\left(\frac{\cosh\rho}{\cosh z}\right)^{1/\rho}} \cdot \sinh z
\end{align}

As we can compare the line 2nd and 4th one I'm not getting the same result I don't know what I'm doing wrong

$$ \frac \partial {\partial z} \left( \sin2\phi \cdot \ln \sqrt[{\Large\,\rho\,}]\frac{\cosh\rho}{\cosh z} \right)=  \frac 1 \rho \cdot \sin2\phi\cdot \left(\frac{\cosh z}{\cosh\rho}\right)\cdot \sinh z$$

Comment: Typesetting advice: trig functions look better if you enter them in MathJax formulas as, for example, `\sin` (producing $\sin\theta$) rather than `sin` (producing $sin\theta$).

Comment: @zipirovich : And the same is true of $\ln,$ thus a\ln b and a\ln(b) look like this: $a\ln b, \quad a\ln(b).$ I included both examples to show that the amount of space before and after (or in this case, after) $\ln$ depends on the context.

Comment: $$ \begin{align} \text{wrong:} \quad & \frac \delta {\delta z} \\  \\ \text{right: } \quad & \frac \partial {\partial z} \end{align} $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Yes, of course, I know. I just didn't notice that these calculations had logs too. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is when you took the derivative of $$\sqrt[\rho]\frac{\cosh \rho}{\cosh z}$$ Yor mistake is that $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\cosh\rho}{\cosh z}\ne \sinh z$ but instead $$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\cosh\rho}{\cosh z}=-\frac{\sinh z \cosh\rho}{\cosh^2 z}$$